# Aborting upload to s3 javascript API

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using Javascript API to upload documents to Amazon S3, and I want to handle cases where the upload to s3 is aborted. May be user closes the browser tab or refresh the page (mainly closing of the browser tab)

Is there a way i can handle the case where i can send a request to my server side code when user aborts s3.upload.

I have the below code

```
    let s3Upload = s3.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
      jQuery('.export-progress').html("Progress: "+ evt.loaded + "/" + evt.total);
    }).promise();

    s3Upload.then(function(s3data){
    //success processing
    }, function(err){
    // any error
    });
```

Any help in this would be really great. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way i can handle the case where i can send a request to my server side code when user aborts s3.upload.

Not really.  The Beacon API can be used to fire off a request if the user closes a tab, but what about cases where their battery dies, browser crashes, computer gets rebooted, etc.?

I usually handle this in one of two ways:

- [Configure a notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) when objects are added, so you can associate the data.
- On upload success (at the client), do a post back to your API to notify it that it succeeded.

Note that both methods are subject to failure, so you should have a cron job or something that regularly sweeps up unexpected items in your bucket, if appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Brad for your reply. I already have a success notification, but I am not sure what happens to the partially uploaded files, because to test what i did was, I uploaded a big file, i was able see the progress of upload in my browser console. But then i closed browser and i did not see the file in my bucket.

Comment: @opensource-developer Partially uploaded files are abandoned.  If you were using multi-part, that's a bit different.  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-multipart-uploads.html)  You do need to consider the case though where the file is successfully uploaded, but the success notification to you doesn't occur.

Comment: thanks @Brad for your reply, I will mark the answer as accepted. I just have one more question, do you know if we are charged anything for the abandoned uploads

Comment: @opensource-developer I'm not 100% sure, but I think you don't pay for storage but you do pay for the bandwidth, and I think you do pay for storage on incomplete multi-part uploads.

Comment: Thanks @Brad for your reply. This is very helpful information